# get value from multiple dropdown and add value to url

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried this code, that can display selected value and refresh the page .

This is the HTML

```
<select name="selectperiode" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Periode">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Yearly</option>
    <option value="4">Quarterly</option>
</select>
```

And this is the JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("[name=selectperiode]").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var stat;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            stat = val;
        }
        else {
            stat = '';
        }
        window.location.href = './corpreport.php?per='+stat;
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine. So I added one more dropdown and added some code with the code below:

```
<select name="selecttype" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Type">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
    <option value="Line">Line</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="Column">Column</option>
</select>
```

And this is the jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("[name=selecttype]").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        var stat;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            stat = val;
        }
        else {
            stat = '';
        }
        window.location.href = './corpreport.php?per=<?php echo $_GET['per']; ?>&type='+stat;
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

It will produce localhost/folder1/file.php?per=1&type=Pie if you choose Yearly and Pie.

But when I change the `periode` to Quarterly, then the link change to `localhost/folder1/file.php?per=4`.

What should I do to make the link localhost/folder1/file.php?per=4&type=Pie ??

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted and vague. please read the following document  on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $("[name=selectperiode]").change(function () {
        window.location.href = period(this) + type($("[name=selecttype]"));
        return true;
    });
    $("[name=selecttype]").change(function () {
        window.location.href = period($("[name=selectperiode]")) + type(this);
        return true;
    });

    function period(element) {
        var val = $(element).val();
        var stat;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            stat = val;
        } else {
            stat = '';
        }
        return './corpreport.php?per=' + stat;
    }

    function type(element) {
        var val = $(element).val();
        var stat;
        if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
            stat = val;
        } else {
            stat = '';
        }
        return '&type=' + stat;
    }
});
```

With this PHP/HTML:

```
<?php
    $per = (!empty($_GET["per"])) ? $_GET["per"] : '';
    $type = (!empty($_GET["type"])) ? $_GET["type"] : '';
?>
<select name="selectperiode" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Periode">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" <?php if($per == "1"){echo "selected";} ?>>Yearly</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($per == "4"){echo "selected";} ?>>Quarterly</option>
</select>
<select name="selecttype" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Type">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pie" <?php if($type == "Pie"){echo "selected";} ?>>Pie</option>
    <option value="Line" <?php if($type == "Line"){echo "selected";} ?>>Line</option>
    <option value="Bar" <?php if($type == "Bar"){echo "selected";} ?>>Bar</option>
    <option value="Column" <?php if($type == "Column"){echo "selected";} ?>>Column</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign ids to both `select` for instance `period`, `type`. Get values of both `selects` on `change` event to make the url.

*Html*

```
<select id="period" name="selectperiode" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Periode">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">Yearly</option>
   <option value="4">Quarterly</option>
</select>


<select id="type"  name="selecttype" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Type">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
        <option value="Line">Line</option>
        <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
        <option value="Column">Column</option>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
$("[name=selecttype]").change(function(){
    var period = document.getElementById('period').value;
    var type = document.getElementById('type').value;
    window.location.href = './corpreport.php?per=' + period  + '&type='+type;
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectperiode" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Periode">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Yearly</option>
    <option value="4">Quarterly</option>
</select>
<select id="selecttype" name="selecttype" style="width:200px;" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Report Type">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pie">Pie</option>
    <option value="Line">Line</option>
    <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="Column">Column</option>
</select>
Jquery
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selecttype").change(function () {
            var period = $("#selectperiode").val();
            var type = $("#selecttype").val();
            window.location.href = './corpreport.php?per=' + period + '&type=' + type;
            return true;

        });
    });
```